# Sorting array using NSSortDescriptor is not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, sorting, nsmutablearray, nssortdescriptor

I have an array with multiple dictionary like:

```
 {
    highRate = "600.49";
    hotelId = 439607;
    hotelRating = "2.5";
    latitude = "12.97153";
    longitude = "80.15096";
    lowRate = "600.49";
    name = "Hotel Kingss Park";
    proximityDistance = "17.999475";
    thumbNailUrl = "http://images.travelnow.com/hotels/7000000/6510000/6500300/6500296/6500296_3_t.jpg";
    tripAdvisorRating = "4.0";
},
    {
    highRate = "990.0";
    hotelId = 327929;
    hotelRating = "2.0";
    latitude = "13.06931";
    longitude = "80.2706";
    lowRate = "450.45";
    name = "Mallika Residency";
    proximityDistance = "1.6274245";
    thumbNailUrl = "http://images.travelnow.com/hotels/3000000/2960000/2958400/2958303/2958303_2_t.jpg";
    tripAdvisorRating = "2.5";
}
```

I try to sort this array using **lowRate** key.

```
NSSortDescriptor *rating_Sort = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"lowRate" ascending:NO];
NSArray *descriptorArray = [NSArray arrayWithObject:rating_Sort];

NSArray *sortedArray = [self.tblDisplayArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:descriptorArray];
```

here **self.tblDisplayArray** is my array.

But not getting proper sorted array in Result.

Why this happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change this

```
 NSSortDescriptor *rating_Sort = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"lowRate.doubleValue" ascending:NO];
```

and it's working fine.

Answer (score 5):

They are all strings so it is attempting to sort them alphabetically not numerically. Try either:

```
NSSortDescriptor *desc = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]initWithKey:@"doubleValue" ascending:YES];
```

or using NSNumbers instead of NSString... @() instead of @"".

@Rajesh is correct, not all your numbers are integers so you should be using doubleValue, I have updated the code!

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

You've array of string which is actually double value. So you sort descriptors as below.

```
    NSSortDescriptor *aSortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"sort" ascending:YES comparator:^(id obj1, id obj2) {
    if ([obj1 doubleValue] < [obj2 doubleValue]) {
        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedAscending;
    }
    return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedSame;
   }];
   sortedArray = [yourArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:aSortDescriptor]];
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Georgegreen pointed they are all strings so it is attempting to sort them alphabetically not numerically.

but you should be using float or double to be precise instead of int.

```
NSSortDescriptor *desc = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]initWithKey:@"doubleValue" ascending:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

Or just do:

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [[yourTempArray sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];
```